# Will the phase shift be mutual if one phase is stepped down through isolated transformer and added to another phase?

Tags: transformer, three-phase, phase-shift, autotransformer

i came across this concept of creating phase shift ( lagging and leading conditions) by adding a stepped down line voltage in series with a different phase voltage. I physically verified the concept too, in a three phase three wire system.

[image]

I was wondering, what might happen if i did the same, instead of using a stepped down line voltage, i wanted to use Y phase in the primary and add the stepped down Y phase voltage in series with R phase.

Will the phase shift happen in R phase alone, or will it be have effect on both the phases?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to make sense. If you have two voltage sources and they are added via a transformer (as I think you imply) to get a new signal with a new phase angle, why should either of the original voltage sources be affected? Adding is nothing other than putting one voltage source in series with another transformer-coupled voltage source. No originating sources are harmed in any way. They are not added by direct parallel connection because that can never work.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm not talking about effect on originating source. Lets say i want to create a single phase imbalance condition using the above mentioned phasor addition of fraction of Y phase to the main R phase voltage, will the effect be mutual. Added one more pic in the query to give an idea.

Comment: What do you mean by mutual in this particular example - try not to use the term mutual because I believe it is confusing the issue.

Comment: @Andyaka Mutual as in the will the phase shift due to phasor addition be applicable for both Y phase and R phase to load. Sorry for the confusion created.

Comment: No, I'm still confused as to what you mean. You also mix up terms like Y source and Y phase and I really genuinely have no idea what you are referring to.

Comment: I will simplify it down... lets say the load is taking normal balanced three phase from the source. I want to create a 4 degree phase shift in the r phase. So, if i step down another phase through a transformer and connect its secondary in series with the R phase, i will get the necessary phase shift, depending on the turns ratio.  My question is, whether the Y phase will get the shifted the same way as the does

Comment: Neither of the originating voltage sources are phase shifted - they are immutable - you are creating a new voltage that has no impact on either phase and, as I said in my first comment `No originating sources are harmed in any way.` - but, as you've dismissed that first comment, I guess I am still not understanding you.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes the originating source wont be harmed. I had a doubt whether this induction will make any shift in the y phase as well and discussing with you was helpful, as i understood where my chain of thought went wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sukrith - this is a Q and A site and "we" like questions to receive a formal answer that you can formally accept. Is it worthwhile me going down this route? [Take the two minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out a little more then let me know. You can answer this question yourself BTW and formally accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is that unlike the r phase voltage provided to load, which is a sum of r phase from source and a stepped down component of Y phase, the Y phase to load doesn't have any series voltage added with it, thereby it remains the same. From source point of view the three phase voltages will remain same as it was before adding the transformer.

Comment: Hi, It seems that you have [answered your own question](/help/self-answer) - ok! So please consider "[accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234)" your answer (or another answer, if a better one has since been added) in a couple of days time - you cannot accept your own answer sooner than 48 hours after you asked the question. Accepting an answer will effectively close the topic by showing that the question has been solved and will remove the question from the unanswered list. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson Yes, i will accept the answer and close the query in 24hrs